# How to reuse feature methods in a @Stepwise Spock specification?

Tags: groovy, spock

I have two Spock specifications, both test a long procedure from a different starting point, so it's like

```
@Stepwise
class FooSpec extends Specification {
    def "setup1"() {...}
    def "setup2"() {...}
    def "common1"() {...}
    def "common2"() {...}
    ...
}

@Stepwise
class BarSpec extends Specification {
    def "setup3"() {...}
    def "setup4"() {...}
    def "common1"() {...}
    def "common2"() {...}
    ...
}
```

Now I'd like to refactor my code to deduplicate all the common* feature methods, that are to be executed after the different setups.

I tried to use subclassing, but the superclass' feature methods are executed *before* and not after the subclass' ones. I also tried to write an own Spock extension (Spock version 0.7 for Groovy 2), but couldn't find a way to implement my desired behaviour there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting the source code of `StepwiseExtension`, I finally managed to come up with my own solution:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtensionAnnotation(BeforeSuperExtension)
@interface BeforeSuper {}
```

This annotation marks feature methods in a `@Stepwise` test, that should be executed before `super`'s feature methods.

The extension implementation will rearrange the execution order accordingly:

```
class BeforeSuperExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<BeforeSuper>
{
    def beforeSuper = []

    @Override
    void visitFeatureAnnotation(BeforeSuper annotation, FeatureInfo feature)
    {
        beforeSuper << feature
    }

    @Override
    void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec)
    {
        def superFeatures = spec.superSpec.allFeaturesInExecutionOrder
        def afterSuper = spec.features - beforeSuper

        (beforeSuper + superFeatures + afterSuper).eachWithIndex { f, i ->
            f.executionOrder = i
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `common*` methods in a base class, and add two subclasses with a `setupSpec()` method (instead of the `setup*` methods).

Comment: The setups are complicated enough to be split up into multiple feature methods. I'd like to retain this granularity.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the opposite strategy, with an annotation `@AfterSubSpec` that tells common methods in the superclass to run after methods in the subclass:

```
class AfterSubSpecExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<AfterSubSpec> {

    def afterSub = []

    @Override
    void visitFeatureAnnotation(AfterSubSpec annotation, FeatureInfo feature) {
        afterSub << feature
    }

    @Override
    void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        def subSpecFeatures = spec.bottomSpec.allFeaturesInExecutionOrder - afterSub

        (subSpecFeatures + afterSub).eachWithIndex { f, i -> f.executionOrder = i }
    }
}
```